# Adding WHERE Clause to Indexed View

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an indexed view along the lines of

```
CREATE VIEW MyView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT a.One, a.Two, b.Three
FROM
Alpha a
INNER JOIN Beta b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

I then create the index with

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_my ON MyView (One, Two)
```

When I attempt to edit the SQL defining the view in the SSMS View Design window to add a filter

```
WHERE a.MyFilter = 0
```

there is an problem upon applying the changes:

> Warning: It is likely that your modification will result in a view that cannot be indexed.

Indeed, if I proceed anyhow the view is updated and the index is dropped.

Can I somehow add my filter condition while maintaining the index?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is possible.

Rather than using the SSMS view designer,

- Drop the view
- Recreate the view by executing `CREATE VIEW MyView ...` in a query window
- Add the index by executing `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED...` in a query window

It is unclear why the view designer does not perform these same steps.  Performing them without the designer results in the index being appropriately created.

Comment: SSMS designers and their "view code" options are good learning tools. Design what you think you need, review the auto-generated code (probably compatible back to SQL 6.5), look all the commands up in Books Online, learn how it all *really* works, then ignore the designers and do serious coding.